# What is Multi-band response?

Tags: filters

What is meaning of multi band response?
I have already tried reading filters texts but no help.
How it is different from simple band pass or band stop

Answer (score 1):

A multi-band filter is, as the name implies, a filter with multiple pass bands and stop bands. [Here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/fir-filter-design.html#f4-7706) is an example of a multi-band filter design.